# How to fix fullscreen @keyframes loader

Tags: css

On my website, I'm trying to make a simple white full-screen loader with one `<div>` element, but instead of going to the right at the end, the `<div>` element goes partially to the left, then snaps to the right. Any ideas on how to fix this? Here's a demo:

```css
body {
background-color: #121212;
}
div#l {
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
background-color: white;
animation: loader 2s infinite;
}
@keyframes loader {
  from {
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
  }
  49% {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
  51% {
    width: 100%;
    right: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='l'></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should divide your `keyframe` in three equal parts.

- `from to 33%`: the white `div` appear
- `from 33% to 66%`: change the `position` of the `div`
- `from 66% to to`: the white `div` disappear

Edit you `keyframe` like this:

```
@keyframes loader {
  from {
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
  }
  33% {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
  66% {
    width: 100%;
    right: 0;
  }
  to {
    right: 0;
    width: 0;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
background-color: #121212;
}
div#l {
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
background-color: white;
animation: loader 2s infinite;
}
@keyframes loader {
  from {
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
  }
  33% {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
  66% {
    width: 100%;
    right: 0;
  }
  to {
    right: 0;
    width: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='l'></div>
```

As you can see in this way the speed of the animation is not linear, and it is not the result we want.

I sugget you to divide the `keyframe` in two parts:

- `from to 50%`: the white `div` appear
- `from 50% to to`: the white `div` move itself to it's max `left position`

Therefore:

```
@keyframes loader {
  from {
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
  }
  50% {
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  to {
    left: 100%;
    width: 0;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
background-color: #121212;
}
div#l {
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
background-color: white;
animation: loader 2s infinite;
}
@keyframes loader {
  from {
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
  }
  50% {
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  to {
    left: 100%;
    width: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='l'></div>
```